# Missing capabilities: Invalid DAV response: Couldn't parse Multi-Status response on REPORT multi-get

Tags: android, adapter, caldav, owncloud, carddav

I have build DAVdroid apk from github https://github.com/bitfireAT/davdroid
when I test unsigned apk wich is generated by debug or run as everythinig is ok and after enter username and password I get list of my calendars and contacts from owncloud server.
But when I sign and export that apk, after install it on phones or tablets and entering username and password, I got error:
"Missing capabilities: Invalid DAV response: Couldn't parse Multi-Status response on REPORT multi-get"

DAVdroid is CAL/CARD DAV adapter for sync caneldars and contacts.